# Need to create PDF from HTML having text, images n bullets

Tags: java, aspose

Present Implementaion for creating PDF from HTML string does not work properly for bullets and images. It crops the image and all bullets are converted to rectangular boxes. I am using  document builder insert html and save pdf methods. These work well without images and bullets

```
    Document doc = new Document();
    DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
    builder.insertHtml(content);//content is html string
    ByteArrayOutputStream dstStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int type = SaveFormat.PDF;  
    builder.getDocument().save(dstStream, type);
```

From the above piece ByteArrayOutputStream is returned and written into a file.
If the html string does not conatin images , it works fine. But if it contains images then the generated image in PDF is cropped and aligned to right.

Comment: Please share your relevant code parts and describe in detail what is not working as expected / intended.

Comment: Yes share the details of code ??

Comment: Edited the question as per comments.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an older version of Aspose.Words, I would suggest you please upgrade to the latest version (v15.6.0) from [here](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx). If the problem still remains, please report the issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) with the input html.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.